# Android Studio building an app: How can one create an onClick event so that something happens with an object once one clicks on the button?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, onclick

Tried to program an Android app in Android Studio with just 2 pics and one button.

First one can see pic1 and the button. I wanted pic2 to change once one clicks on the button to pic2.

But it doesn't work out.
The build window told me that there is a compilation error and I should look into log for more details.

And in the editor there is told that the onClick method does not exist.

What have I done to get the programm work:

I went to the editor to the button and to its attributes and wrote "change" next to onClick.
I went to MainActivity.kt and wrote the following:

```
package com.example.myfirstkotlin

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    }
    fun change (view: button) {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.h)

    }
}
```

What have I done in a wrong way? Can somebody help me?

Edit: Catlog:

```
2019-04-15 17:08:59.902 1516-1526/? E/vold: Failed to chmod /data/system_ce/0: No such file or directory
2019-04-15 17:08:59.902 1516-1526/? E/vold: Failed to chmod /data/misc_ce/0: No such file or directory
2019-04-15 17:08:59.902 1516-1526/? E/vold: Failed to chmod /data/media/0: No such file or directory
2019-04-15 17:09:02.909 1575-1575/? E/GoldfishGatekeeper: called goldfish_gatekeeper_open with gate keeper 0xf511b0d8 device 0xf4de5088
2019-04-15 17:09:04.036 1578-1578/? E/hwcomposer: unknown display attribute 6
2019-04-15 17:09:05.076 1569-1569/? E/EmulatedCamera_Factory: 2 cameras are being emulated. 1 of them are fake cameras.
2019-04-15 17:09:05.158 1569-1569/? E/EmulatedCamera_HotplugThread: createFileIfNotExists: Could not create file '/data/misc/media/emulator.camera.hotplug.0', error: 'No such file or directory' (2)
2019-04-15 17:09:05.158 1569-1569/? E/EmulatedCamera_HotplugThread: createFileIfNotExists: Could not create file '/data/misc/media/emulator.camera.hotplug.1', error: 'No such file or directory' (2)
2019-04-15 17:09:05.159 1569-1569/? E/CamProvider@2.4-impl: setUpVendorTags: Vendor tag operations not fully defined. Ignoring definitions.
2019-04-15 17:09:05.159 1569-1569/? E/CamProvider@2.4-impl: initialize: Vendor tag setup failed, will not be available.
2019-04-15 17:09:05.986 1567-1567/? E/audiohalservice: Could not get passthrough implementation for android.hardware.soundtrigger@2.1::ISoundTriggerHw/default.
2019-04-15 17:09:06.092 1567-1567/? E/SoundTriggerHalImpl: couldn't load sound trigger module sound_trigger.primary (No such file or directory)
2019-04-15 17:09:06.096 1567-1567/? E/audiohalservice: Could not get passthrough implementation for android.hardware.bluetooth.a2dp@1.0::IBluetoothAudioOffload/default.
2019-04-15 17:09:06.114 1587-1587/? E/vndksupport: Could not load /vendor/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so from sphal namespace: dlopen failed: library "/vendor/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so" not found.
2019-04-15 17:09:06.114 1587-1587/? E/libEGL: load_driver(/vendor/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so): unknown
2019-04-15 17:09:07.080 1587-1587/? E/HWComposer: getSupportedPerFrameMetadata: getSupportedPerFrameMetadata failed for display 0: Unsupported (8)
2019-04-15 17:09:15.186 1587-1634/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
2019-04-15 17:09:15.242 1648-1671/? E/vndksupport: Could not load /vendor/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so from sphal namespace: dlopen failed: library "/vendor/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so" not found.
2019-04-15 17:09:15.242 1648-1671/? E/libEGL: load_driver(/vendor/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so): unknown
2019-04-15 17:09:17.443 1678-1678/? E/vndksupport: Could not load /vendor/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so from sphal namespace: dlopen failed: library "/vendor/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so" not found.
2019-04-15 17:09:17.444 1678-1678/? E/libEGL: load_driver(/vendor/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so): unknown
2019-04-15 17:09:17.645 1713-1713/? E/hwcomposer: unknown display attribute 6
2019-04-15 17:09:18.496 1678-1678/? E/HWComposer: getSupportedPerFrameMetadata: getSupportedPerFrameMetadata failed for display 0: Unsupported (8)
2019-04-15 17:09:19.569 1681-1681/? E/CameraHardwareInterface: initialize: openSession failed! No such file or directory (-2)
2019-04-15 17:09:19.569 1681-1681/? E/CameraFlashlight: connectCameraDevice: initializing camera 0 failed
2019-04-15 17:09:19.569 1681-1681/? E/CameraFlashlight: findFlashUnits: failed to check if camera 0 has a flash unit. No such file or directory (-2)
2019-04-15 17:09:19.578 1681-1681/? E/CameraHardwareInterface: initialize: openSession failed! No such file or directory (-2)
2019-04-15 17:09:19.578 1681-1681/? E/CameraFlashlight: connectCameraDevice: initializing camera 1 failed
2019-04-15 17:09:19.579 1681-1681/? E/CameraFlashlight: findFlashUnits: failed to check if camera 1 has a flash unit. No such file or directory (-2)
2019-04-15 17:09:19.584 1681-1754/? E/CameraService: onDeviceStatusChanged: State transition to the same status 0x1 not allowed
2019-04-15 17:09:19.585 1681-1754/? E/CameraService: onDeviceStatusChanged: State transition to the same status 0x1 not allowed
2019-04-15 17:09:19.717 1757-1757/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument
2019-04-15 17:09:19.717 1757-1757/? E/netmgr: WifiForwarder unable to open QEMU pipe: Invalid argument
2019-04-15 17:09:20.349 1699-1699/? E/Netd: cannot find interface dummy0
2019-04-15 17:09:20.354 1678-1688/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
2019-04-15 17:09:20.359 1699-1699/? E/Netd: Unable to create netlink socket: Protocol not supported
2019-04-15 17:09:20.380 1777-1795/? E/vndksupport: Could not load /vendor/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so from sphal namespace: dlopen failed: library "/vendor/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so" not found.
2019-04-15 17:09:20.380 1777-1795/? E/libEGL: load_driver(/vendor/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so): unknown
2019-04-15 17:09:20.615 1704-1704/? E/vndksupport: Could not load libstagefrighthw.so from default namespace: dlopen failed: library "libstagefrighthw.so" not found.
2019-04-15 17:09:21.248 1818-1818/? E/ipv6proxy: Failed to forward Neighbor Solicitation for fe80::f80e:15ff:febb:6c56 from radio0-peer to eth0: Cannot assign requested address
2019-04-15 17:09:21.798 1821-1821/? E/hostapd: Configuration file: /data/vendor/wifi/hostapd/hostapd.conf
2019-04-15 17:09:22.255 1818-1818/? E/ipv6proxy: Failed to forward Router Advertisement from eth0 to wlan1: Network is unreachable
2019-04-15 17:09:22.256 1818-1818/? E/ipv6proxy: Failed to forward Router Advertisement from eth0 to radio0-peer: Cannot assign requested address
2019-04-15 17:09:23.688 1702-1727/? E/storaged: getService package_native failed
2019-04-15 17:09:23.727 1702-1727/? E/storaged: getDiskStats failed with result NOT_SUPPORTED and size 0
2019-04-15 17:09:26.266 1777-1831/? E/BootAnimation: Could not add watch for /data/system
2019-04-15 17:09:26.587 1818-1818/? E/ipv6proxy: Failed to forward Router Advertisement from eth0 to wlan1: Network is unreachable
2019-04-15 17:09:28.235 1821-1821/? E/hostapd: Using interface wlan1 with hwaddr 02:00:00:00:01:00 and ssid "AndroidWifi"
2019-04-15 17:09:28.831 1702-1727/? E/storaged: getService package_native failed
2019-04-15 17:09:39.556 1680-1680/? E/ActivityRecognitionHardware: activity_recognition HAL is deprecated. class_init is effectively a no-op
2019-04-15 17:09:46.370 1680-1680/? E/vndksupport: Could not load /vendor/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so from sphal namespace: dlopen failed: library "/vendor/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so" not found.
2019-04-15 17:09:46.370 1680-1680/? E/libEGL: load_driver(/vendor/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so): unknown
2019-04-15 17:09:47.296 1844-1844/? E/system_server: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
2019-04-15 17:09:51.424 1844-1844/? E/UsbAlsaJackDetectorJNI: Can't register UsbAlsaJackDetector native methods
2019-04-15 17:09:53.608 1844-1864/? E/BluetoothAdapter: Bluetooth binder is null
2019-04-15 17:09:53.652 1844-1844/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2019-04-15 17:09:53.669 1844-1864/? E/BatteryExternalStatsWorker: no controller energy info supplied for telephony
2019-04-15 17:09:53.716 1844-1864/? E/KernelUidCpuFreqTimeReader: Failed to read /proc/uid_time_in_state: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/uid_time_in_state (No such file or directory)
2019-04-15 17:09:53.860 1844-1864/? E/KernelUidCpuFreqTimeReader: Failed to read /proc/uid_time_in_state: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/uid_time_in_state (No such file or directory)
2019-04-15 17:09:54.998 1678-1832/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
2019-04-15 17:09:55.001 1844-1868/? E/LocalDisplayAdapter: Default and active color mode is no longer available! Reverting to first available mode.
2019-04-15 17:09:55.241 1844-1868/? E/LightsService: Unable to get ILight interface.
2019-04-15 17:10:04.343 1585-1585/? E/SoundTriggerHwService: could not read implementation properties
2019-04-15 17:10:04.675 1844-1901/? E/SensorService: Reported power 0.000000 not deemed sane, clamping to 0.001000
2019-04-15 17:10:05.458 1844-1858/? E/SystemServer: Unable to preload default resources
2019-04-15 17:10:06.377 1844-1844/? E/VibratorService: vibratorOff command failed (1).
2019-04-15 17:10:09.598 1844-1864/? E/KernelUidCpuFreqTimeReader: Failed to read /proc/uid_time_in_state: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/uid_time_in_state (No such file or directory)
2019-04-15 17:10:10.037 1844-1917/? E/EventHub: could not get driver version for /dev/input/mice, Not a typewriter
2019-04-15 17:10:12.159 1516-1516/? E/vold: Failed to read field SystemLocale: No such file or directory
2019-04-15 17:10:12.167 1844-1919/? E/StorageManagerService: Failed to read field SystemLocale
    android.os.ServiceSpecificException: Failed to read field SystemLocale (code 2)
        at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:1956)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1910)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1860)
        at android.os.IVold$Stub$Proxy.fdeGetField(IVold.java:1094)
        at com.android.server.StorageManagerService.getField(StorageManagerService.java:2408)
        at com.android.server.StorageManagerService.copyLocaleFromMountService(StorageManagerService.java:982)
        at com.android.server.StorageManagerService.handleDaemonConnected(StorageManagerService.java:975)
        at com.android.server.StorageManagerService.access$900(StorageManagerService.java:171)
        at com.android.server.StorageManagerService$StorageManagerServiceHandler.handleMessage(StorageManagerService.java:572)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
2019-04-15 17:10:16.386 1844-1844/? E/WifiStateMachine: getWifiLinkLayerStats called without an interface
2019-04-15 17:10:16.641 1844-1844/? E/SupplicantStaIfaceHal: Can't call setDebugParams, ISupplicant is null
2019-04-15 17:10:19.160 1844-1844/? E/UsbDeviceManager: failed to write to /sys/class/android_usb/android0/f_rndis/ethaddr
2019-04-15 17:10:19.300 1844-1844/? E/UsbDeviceManagerJNI: could not open control for mtp No such file or directory
2019-04-15 17:10:19.301 1844-1844/? E/UsbDeviceManager: Failed to open control for mtp
2019-04-15 17:10:19.301 1844-1844/? E/UsbDeviceManagerJNI: could not open control for ptp No such file or directory
2019-04-15 17:10:19.301 1844-1844/? E/UsbDeviceManager: Failed to open control for mtp
2019-04-15 17:10:19.536 1844-1844/? E/UsbDeviceManagerJNI: could not open /dev/usb_accessory
2019-04-15 17:10:19.568 1844-1844/? E/UsbPortManager: connectToProxy: usb hal service not found. Did the service fail to start?
    java.util.NoSuchElementException
        at android.os.HwBinder.getService(Native Method)
        at android.os.HwBinder.getService(HwBinder.java:91)
        at android.hardware.usb.V1_0.IUsb.getService(IUsb.java:48)
        at android.hardware.usb.V1_0.IUsb.getService(IUsb.java:52)
        at com.android.server.usb.UsbPortManager.connectToProxy(UsbPortManager.java:531)
        at com.android.server.usb.UsbPortManager.<init>(UsbPortManager.java:137)
        at com.android.server.usb.UsbService.<init>(UsbService.java:142)
        at com.android.server.usb.UsbService$Lifecycle.onStart(UsbService.java:73)
        at com.android.server.SystemServiceManager.startService(SystemServiceManager.java:126)
        at com.android.server.SystemServiceManager.startService(SystemServiceManager.java:113)
        at com.android.server.SystemServiceManager.startService(SystemServiceManager.java:72)
        at com.android.server.SystemServer.startOtherServices(SystemServer.java:1299)
        at com.android.server.SystemServer.run(SystemServer.java:431)
        at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:294)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:838)
2019-04-15 17:10:19.579 1844-1844/? E/HardwarePropertiesManagerService-JNI: Unable to get Thermal service.
2019-04-15 17:10:19.769 1757-1757/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument
2019-04-15 17:10:19.769 1757-1757/? E/netmgr: WifiForwarder unable to open QEMU pipe: Invalid argument
2019-04-15 17:10:21.786 1712-1712/? E/FingerprintHal: Could not load fingerprints from storage at /data/vendor_de/0/fpdata/emufp.bin; it has not yet been created.
2019-04-15 17:10:21.812 1844-1844/? E/KernelUidCpuFreqTimeReader: Failed to read /proc/uid_time_in_state: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/uid_time_in_state (No such file or directory)
2019-04-15 17:10:22.229 1844-1844/? E/LockSettingsStorage: Cannot read file java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/system/gatekeeper.password.key: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
2019-04-15 17:10:22.230 1844-1844/? E/LockSettingsStorage: Cannot read file java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/system/password.key: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
2019-04-15 17:10:22.237 1844-1844/? E/LockSettingsStorage: Cannot read file java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/system/gatekeeper.pattern.key: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
2019-04-15 17:10:22.238 1844-1844/? E/LockSettingsStorage: Cannot read file java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/system/gatekeeper.gesture.key: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
2019-04-15 17:10:22.239 1844-1844/? E/LockSettingsStorage: Cannot read file java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/system/gesture.key: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
2019-04-15 17:10:26.006 1582-1582/? E/android.hardware.wifi@1.0-service: Failed to register radio mode change callback
2019-04-15 17:10:26.023 1582-1582/? E/android.hardware.wifi@1.0-service: Failed to set DFS flag; DFS channels may be unavailable.
2019-04-15 17:10:26.144 1703-1703/? E/wificond: No Offload Service available
2019-04-15 17:10:26.221 1844-1927/? E/SupplicantStaIfaceHal: Can't call setupIface, ISupplicantStaIface is null
2019-04-15 17:10:26.669 1956-1956/? E/putmethod.lati: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
2019-04-15 17:10:26.686 1844-1844/? E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/system/users/0/wallpaper_orig (No such file or directory)
2019-04-15 17:10:26.688 1844-1844/? E/WallpaperManagerService: Unable to apply new wallpaper
2019-04-15 17:10:26.736 1844-1938/? E/BluetoothAdapter: Bluetooth binder is null
2019-04-15 17:10:26.740 1844-1938/? E/BluetoothAdapter: Bluetooth binder is null
2019-04-15 17:10:26.890 1973-1973/? E/ndroid.systemu: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
2019-04-15 17:10:27.454 1695-1776/? E/linker: library "/system/lib/extractors/.." ("/system/lib") needed or dlopened by "/system/lib/libstagefright.so" is not accessible for the namespace: [name="(default)", ld_library_paths="", default_library_paths="/system/lib", permitted_paths="/system/lib/drm:/system/lib/extractors:/system/lib/hw:/system/product/lib:/system/framework:/system/app:/system/priv-app:/vendor/framework:/vendor/app:/vendor/priv-app:/odm/framework:/odm/app:/odm/priv-app:/oem/app:/system/product/framework:/system/product/app:/system/product/priv-app:/data:/mnt/expand"]
2019-04-15 17:10:27.709 1695-1776/? E/MediaExtractorFactory: couldn't opendir(/vendor/lib/extractors)
2019-04-15 17:10:27.848 1844-1864/? E/BatteryExternalStatsWorker: no controller energy info supplied for wifi
2019-04-15 17:10:27.892 1995-1995/? E/WebViewLoader-: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
2019-04-15 17:10:27.933 1844-1864/? E/BatteryExternalStatsWorker: no controller energy info supplied for wifi
2019-04-15 17:10:27.934 1844-1864/? E/BatteryExternalStatsWorker: no controller energy info supplied for telephony
2019-04-15 17:10:27.935 1844-1864/? E/KernelUidCpuFreqTimeReader: Failed to read /proc/uid_time_in_state: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/uid_time_in_state (No such file or directory)
2019-04-15 17:10:28.847 1702-1727/? E/storaged: getDiskStats failed with result NOT_SUPPORTED and size 0
2019-04-15 17:10:28.865 1576-1576/? E/GnssHAL_GnssInterface: getExtensionAGnss: AGnss interface not implemented by HAL
2019-04-15 17:10:28.898 1576-1576/? E/GnssHAL_GnssInterface: getExtensionGnssMeasurement: GnssMeasurement interface not implemented by HAL
2019-04-15 17:10:28.924 1844-1844/? E/ActivityRecognitionHardware: activity_recognition HAL is deprecated. is_supported is effectively a no-op
2019-04-15 17:10:28.945 1576-1576/? E/GnssHAL_GnssInterface: getExtensionGnssConfiguration: GnssConfiguration interface not implemented by HAL
2019-04-15 17:10:28.945 1576-1576/? E/GnssHAL_GnssInterface: getExtensionGnssGeofencing: GnssGeofencing interface not implemented by HAL
2019-04-15 17:10:28.945 1576-1576/? E/GnssHAL_GnssInterface: gnss flp hw_get_module failed: -2
2019-04-15 17:10:28.945 1576-1576/? E/GnssHAL_GnssInterface: getExtensionGnssBatching: GnssBatching interface is not implemented by HAL
2019-04-15 17:10:28.948 1844-1859/? E/GnssLocationProvider: Unable to initialize GNSS Xtra interface
2019-04-15 17:10:29.024 1844-1859/? E/GnssLocationProvider: no AGPS interface in set_agps_server
2019-04-15 17:10:29.162 1844-1859/? E/GnssLocationProvider: Unable to initialize GNSS Xtra interface
2019-04-15 17:10:29.170 1844-1859/? E/GnssLocationProvider: no AGPS interface in set_agps_server
2019-04-15 17:10:29.175 1844-1859/? E/GnssBatchingProvider: Failed to initialize GNSS batching
2019-04-15 17:10:29.459 2000-2000/? E/webviewchromiumloader: Failed to open relro file /data/misc/shared_relro/libwebviewchromium32.relro: No such file or directory
2019-04-15 17:10:30.592 1704-1704/? E/OMXNodeInstance: getExtensionIndex(0xf01981e0:google.h264.decoder, OMX.google.android.index.configureVideoTunnelMode) ERROR: UnsupportedIndex(0x8000101a)
2019-04-15 17:10:30.596 1704-1704/? E/OMXNodeInstance: getExtensionIndex(0xf01981e0:google.h264.decoder, OMX.google.android.index.enableAndroidNativeBuffers) ERROR: UnsupportedIndex(0x8000101a)
2019-04-15 17:10:30.973 1704-1704/? E/OMXNodeInstance: getExtensionIndex(0xf0198240:google.h263.decoder, OMX.google.android.index.configureVideoTunnelMode) ERROR: UnsupportedIndex(0x8000101a)
2019-04-15 17:10:30.975 1704-1704/? E/OMXNodeInstance: getExtensionIndex(0xf0198240:google.h263.decoder, OMX.google.android.index.enableAndroidNativeBuffers) ERROR: UnsupportedIndex(0x8000101a)
2019-04-15 17:10:31.226 1704-1704/? E/OMXNodeInstance: getExtensionIndex(0xf0198240:google.hevc.decoder, OMX.google.android.index.configureVideoTunnelMode) ERROR: UnsupportedIndex(0x8000101a)
2019-04-15 17:10:31.243 1704-1704/? E/OMXNodeInstance: getExtensionIndex(0xf0198240:google.hevc.decoder, OMX.google.android.index.enableAndroidNativeBuffers) ERROR: UnsupportedIndex(0x8000101a)
2019-04-15 17:10:31.315 1704-1811/? E/OMXNodeInstance: getExtensionIndex(0xf0198060:google.mpeg4.decoder, OMX.google.android.index.configureVideoTunnelMode) ERROR: UnsupportedIndex(0x8000101a)
2019-04-15 17:10:31.317 1704-1811/? E/OMXNodeInstance: getExtensionIndex(0xf0198060:google.mpeg4.decoder, OMX.google.android.index.enableAndroidNativeBuffers) ERROR: UnsupportedIndex(0x8000101a)
2019-04-15 17:10:31.503 1704-1811/? E/OMXNodeInstance: getExtensionIndex(0xf01982a0:google.vp8.decoder, OMX.google.android.index.configureVideoTunnelMode) ERROR: UnsupportedIndex(0x8000101a)
2019-04-15 17:10:31.514 1704-1811/? E/OMXNodeInstance: getExtensionIndex(0xf01982a0:google.vp8.decoder, OMX.google.android.index.enableAndroidNativeBuffers) ERROR: UnsupportedIndex(0x8000101a)
2019-04-15 17:10:31.639 1844-1864/? E/KernelUidCpuFreqTimeReader: Failed to read /proc/uid_time_in_state: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/uid_time_in_state (No such file or directory)
2019-04-15 17:10:31.698 1844-1844/? E/SystemServerTiming: SystemServer init took too long. uptimeMillis=106695
2019-04-15 17:10:31.700 1704-1811/? E/OMXNodeInstance: getExtensionIndex(0xf0198060:google.vp9.decoder, OMX.google.android.index.configureVideoTunnelMode) ERROR: UnsupportedIndex(0x8000101a)
2019-04-15 17:10:31.708 1704-1811/? E/OMXNodeInstance: getExtensionIndex(0xf0198060:google.vp9.decoder, OMX.google.android.index.enableAndroidNativeBuffers) ERROR: UnsupportedIndex(0x8000101a)
2019-04-15 17:10:32.015 2076-2076/? E/m.android.phon: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
2019-04-15 17:10:32.025 2081-2081/? E/ndroid.setting: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
2019-04-15 17:10:32.268 1844-1929/? E/WifiP2pService: Unexpected disable request when WifiChannel is null
2019-04-15 17:10:32.527 1704-1704/? E/OMXNodeInstance: getConfig(0xf0198060:google.h263.encoder, ConfigAndroidIntraRefresh(0x6f60000a)) ERROR: Undefined(0x80001001)
2019-04-15 17:10:32.725 1704-1704/? E/OMXNodeInstance: getConfig(0xf01982a0:google.mpeg4.encoder, ConfigAndroidIntraRefresh(0x6f60000a)) ERROR: Undefined(0x80001001)
2019-04-15 17:10:33.054 1704-2028/? E/OMXNodeInstance: getConfig(0xf0198420:google.vp8.encoder, ConfigAndroidIntraRefresh(0x6f60000a)) ERROR: Undefined(0x80001001)
2019-04-15 17:10:33.250 1704-2028/? E/OMXNodeInstance: getConfig(0xf0198420:google.vorbis.decoder, ConfigAndroidVendorExtension(0x6f100004)) ERROR: Undefined(0x80001001)
2019-04-15 17:10:34.275 1704-2028/? E/OMXNodeInstance: getConfig(0xf0198420:google.vorbis.decoder, ConfigAndroidVendorExtension(0x6f100004)) ERROR: Undefined(0x80001001)
2019-04-15 17:10:35.496 1844-1859/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2019-04-15 17:10:35.717 1678-1687/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
2019-04-15 17:10:35.727 1844-1844/? E/BluetoothAdapter: Bluetooth binder is null
2019-04-15 17:10:35.905 1704-1811/? E/OMXNodeInstance: getConfig(0xf01984e0:google.vorbis.decoder, ConfigAndroidVendorExtension(0x6f100004)) ERROR: Undefined(0x80001001)
2019-04-15 17:10:36.251 1678-1687/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
2019-04-15 17:10:36.611 1704-1704/? E/OMXNodeInstance: getConfig(0xf05a6ae0:google.vorbis.decoder, ConfigAndroidVendorExtension(0x6f100004)) ERROR: Undefined(0x80001001)
2019-04-15 17:10:37.100 1844-1844/? E/BluetoothAdapter: Bluetooth binder is null
2019-04-15 17:10:37.246 1844-1844/? E/BluetoothAdapter: Bluetooth binder is null
2019-04-15 17:10:37.448 1844-1928/? E/WifiVendorHal: getBgScanCapabilities(l.671) failed {.code = ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED, .description = }
2019-04-15 17:10:37.577 1704-1812/? E/OMXNodeInstance: getConfig(0xf01984e0:google.vorbis.decoder, ConfigAndroidVendorExtension(0x6f100004)) ERROR: Undefined(0x80001001)
2019-04-15 17:10:38.143 1704-2131/? E/OMXNodeInstance: getConfig(0xf05a6ba0:google.vorbis.decoder, ConfigAndroidVendorExtension(0x6f100004)) ERROR: Undefined(0x80001001)
2019-04-15 17:10:38.257 1844-1844/? E/WiredAccessoryManager: No state change.
2019-04-15 17:10:38.585 2076-2076/? E/CarrierIdProvider: read carrier list from ota pb failure: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/misc/carrierid/carrier_list.pb (No such file or directory)
2019-04-15 17:10:39.036 1704-2131/? E/OMXNodeInstance: getConfig(0xf05a6c00:google.vorbis.decoder, ConfigAndroidVendorExtension(0x6f100004)) ERROR: Undefined(0x80001001)
2019-04-15 17:10:39.744 1704-2131/? E/OMXNodeInstance: getConfig(0xf05a6cc0:google.vorbis.decoder, ConfigAndroidVendorExtension(0x6f100004)) ERROR: Undefined(0x80001001)
2019-04-15 17:10:40.067 2165-2165/? E/id.ext.service: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
2019-04-15 17:10:40.836 1844-1936/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.android.calendar
2019-04-15 17:10:40.867 1844-1936/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.android.calendar
2019-04-15 17:10:41.041 1704-1704/? E/OMXNodeInstance: getConfig(0xf05a6cc0:google.vorbis.decoder, ConfigAndroidVendorExtension(0x6f100004)) ERROR: Undefined(0x80001001)
2019-04-15 17:10:41.585 1844-1844/? E/AutofillManagerServiceImpl: Bad AutofillService name: com.google.android.gms/.autofill.service.AutofillService
2019-04-15 17:10:41.586 1844-1844/? E/AutofillManagerServiceImpl: Bad AutofillService name: com.google.android.gms/.autofill.service.AutofillService
2019-04-15 17:10:43.420 1844-1859/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2019-04-15 17:10:45.277 1678-1688/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
2019-04-15 17:10:47.926 2076-2226/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.android.contacts
2019-04-15 17:10:47.988 2076-2076/? E/BluetoothAdapter: Bluetooth binder is null
2019-04-15 17:10:59.784 2076-2076/? E/PhoneInterfaceManager: [PhoneIntfMgr] getIccId: No UICC
2019-04-15 17:11:00.204 1973-1973/? E/BluetoothAdapter: Bluetooth binder is null
2019-04-15 17:11:00.872 2076-2076/? E/PhoneInterfaceManager: [PhoneIntfMgr] getIccId: No UICC
2019-04-15 17:11:02.794 1973-2228/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.android.contacts
2019-04-15 17:11:03.756 2076-2076/? E/PhoneInterfaceManager: [PhoneIntfMgr] getIccId: No UICC
2019-04-15 17:11:05.140 1844-1859/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2019-04-15 17:11:07.249 1678-1803/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
```

2019-04-15 17:11:07.573 2076-2076/? E/PhoneInterfaceManager: [PhoneIntfMgr] getIccId: No UICC
2019-04-15 17:11:07.612 2076-2076/? E/PhoneInterfaceManager: [PhoneIntfMgr] getIccId: No UICC
2019-04-15 17:11:07.797 1844-1859/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2019-04-15 17:11:08.155 1973-2228/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.android.contacts
2019-04-15 17:11:08.226 1844-1859/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2019-04-15 17:11:08.462 1844-1859/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2019-04-15 17:11:08.485 1973-2223/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.android.contacts
2019-04-15 17:11:08.503 1844-1859/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2019-04-15 17:11:08.590 1844-1859/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module

Comment: Add the error log.

Comment: I added it now. And sorry I am new to this here.

Comment: Those logs are unrelated to your crash. You're looking for a large section of red lines that starts with `FATAL EXCEPTION`. Also, the parameter type for the function corresponding to an `onClick` attribute must be `View`. That is, `fun change (view: View)`.

Comment: I've tried it with the parameter "View" but it also hasn't worked out...

Answer (score 0):

try to change button to Button

```
 fun change (view: Button) {

 }
```

Comment: A change from button to Button has changed nothing at all. Same error.

Comment: you try to access imageView directly from code, like there are kotlin extensions enabled. But I don't see such import in your class.

Comment: How can I import such an import?

Comment: There is so much lack of info about your issue, that its hard to answer correctly. If you are beginner to android development, you should follow tutorials and see how its done there. Get some practice.

Comment: I have done a tutorial on Udemy to do this but it hasn't worked out. That's why I am asking here why it doesn't work.

Comment: Try to watch line after line, symbol-to-symbol how they're doing there.

Comment: This won't change things much